# Game Monster AI C++

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I'm about to implement simple "aggro" AI for my game monsters. There are about 30000 monsters ingame, each monster object pointer is stored in `std::map`. Simple "aggro" means walking from time to time and chasing player.

My approach would be to start a thread and iterate through `std::map` each 30ms to check if monster should make a step towards player or if it's time for a walk (each 20s). Also if player is not too far away, so it could stop chasing him.

The problem is, it consumes alot of CPU. So another idea would be to add second `std::map` with copies of pointers to objects that are currently "active" and iterate through "active" only. By active, I mean they are in walk state or chase state. It could be less CPU consuming because in most of the time 95% monsters are in idle state. But still, there would be alot of insert/erase operations on second map.

Is there any better solution to this problem?

Comment: You should only move monsters that are within the player's view, or are within a given distance of the player.

Comment: There is much info missing to reason about these statistics. But i can't image there would be so many insert/erase operations in the auxiliary-map. This approach sounds quite good. But maybe it's more about the core-calculations inside these decisions. And 30000 objects sound like a lot. Maybe you are forced to approximate the desired behaviour by calling less frequently (maybe only pixel-changes matter to the user). Thomas comment is also very important. But we don't know your kind of "game". So maybe all are seen (which sounds like chaos) or not.

Comment: [Space partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) can help with determining which monsters are close to the player.